# Information interpretations of QM

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, resource-recommendations, quantum-interpretations

There are now several good books on QM interpretations, some popular, some advanced-popular. I've read a couple. At best, they mention information-theory interpretation, but without explaining how they work (like Becker's recent book). Is there a good popular or student-level text on this type of interpretation?

(Note: I'm not looking for a book on quantum computation, per se.)

Comment: So is information theory interpretation distinct from [information theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_theory)? While I don't claim much knowledge in the QM interpretation landscape, the phrase you're looking for is not something I find with Google searches

Answer (score 3):

The various interpretations of quantum mechanics can be classified under either epistemic interpretation or ontic interpretation. In the ontic interpretations, the reality is given importance (this includes the many world interpretation and all that). In epistemic interpretations, the information carried by the state is given importance. Here is a short list,

L Ballentine, Statistical Interpretation of Quantum Mechanics. Rev. Mod. Phys. 42, 358, 1970

C A Fuchs, A Peres, Quantum Theory Needs No `Interpretation'. Physics Today 53, 3, 70, 2000

C A Fuchs, Quantum Mechanics as Quantum Information (and only a little more). https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0205039, 2002

C A Fuchs, N D Mermin, R Schack, An Introduction to QBism with an Application to the Locality of Quantum Mechanics. https://arxiv.org/abs/1311.5253, 2013

R Clifton, J Bub, H Halvorson, Characterizing Quantum Theory in terms of Information-Theoretic Constraints. https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0211089, 2002

C Rovelli, Relational Quantum Mechanics. https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/9609002, 1996

R Spekkens, In defense of the epistemic view of quantum states: a toy theory. https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0401052, 2005

M Pusey, J Barrett, T Rudolph, On the reality of the quantum state.
https://arxiv.org/abs/1111.3328, 2012

C A Fuchs, On Participatory Realism. https://arxiv.org/abs/1601.04360, 2016

A Cabello, Interpretations of Quantum Theory: A Map of Madness. http://arxiv.org/abs/1509.04711, 2015

R P Kostecki, Quantum theory as inductive inference.    http://arxiv.org/abs/1009.2423v4, 2010

R P Kostecki, https://www.fuw.edu.pl/~kostecki/talk_2016.05.04_waterloo.pdf, 2016

You might also want to look into generalized probability theories or operational probability theories. The works of Mackey, Gunther Ludwig, for example, are good. The book Operational Quantum Physics by Paul Busch, et al is really good. You can find more good references from the bibliography of the above list.

If you don't have the required background you could skim through C Fuchs' papers.